# MySQL: Extract data for line graph to show counts over time period

Tags: mysql

I have a table which captures when certain events (say alien attacks) happened. Each time the aliens attack a new record is created in this table (some days can have multiple attacks and some days none)..

```
   attack_id         attack_date
   ---------         ---------
   1                 03/12/2015
   2                 03/12/2015
   3                 04/01/2015
   4                 04/21/2015
   5                 06/14/2015
```

I want to show in a line graph how many attacks occured per week. So the x-axis would be weeks in the year and the y-axis would be the number attacks in that week.

Thus the result set to feed my graph might look like

```
Week            Number of attacks
----            -----------------
```

Can someone suggest a mysql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two things you need: `week()` function to get the week from the date, and `count()` to get how many attacks happened:

```
SELECT WEEK(alien_date) as attack_week, COUNT(*) as num_of_attacks 
 FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY WEEK(alien_date)
```

Comment: could you also share how I can add a row with '0'  in the result set for the weeks when no attacks happened?

Comment: @AbuMariam - take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305085/including-missing-zero-count-rows-when-using-group-by

Comment: Thanks Nir Levy, I thought there would be an easy way to do it through SQL, looks like I will have to do it in the UI.