# Get all months from a query including zero counts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, mysqli

I have this query now:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`dataNl`, \'%Y%m\') AS `Ym`, COUNT(*) AS `totale`
FROM `noleggio`
GROUP BY `Ym`
```

This help to get data for each month, but if a month with 0 value, this doesn't exist in the database, so I can't get it. I need a query that add remaining month setting the `COUNT` field to `0`.

I made a PHP code to add months with 0 value into the array, but it only works if the year is only one, if I want to get more, this needs a lot of tricky code, I think there could be a solution with SQL.

This is the PHP code:

```
$t = array();
$m = array();
foreach ($months as $val) {
    $t[] = $val['totale'];
    $m[] = $val['Ym'];
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 12; ++$i) {
    if (in_array($i + 201801, $m) == false) {
        array_splice($t, $i, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `having` clause in query with count >= 0.

Comment: You need a calendar table. If you google it, there are many examples how to make and use one.

Comment: Add Group BY Month

Comment: @RevathiGanesh i tried but doesn't work

Comment: Create a months help table, that contains all needed months. Outer join that table.

Comment: I agree with HoneyBadger and jarlh.  The tidiest solution would be to perform all of the logic in sql.  Here is one page to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24305085/2943403  (there are many on SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PHP solution which requires min and max dates from the database:

```
// use the query SELECT MIN(dataNl), MAX(dataNl) FROM ... to
// find the first and last date in your data and use them below
$dates = new DatePeriod(
    DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d|', '2018-01-15')->modify('first day of this month'),
    new DateInterval('P1M'),
    DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d|', '2018-12-15')->modify('first day of next month')
);

// assuming $rows contain the result of the GROUP BY query...
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $datestr = $date->format('Ym');
    $index = array_search($datestr, array_column($rows, 'Ym'));
    if ($index === false) {
        echo $datestr . ' -> 0' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $datestr . ' -> ' . $months[$index]['totale'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`dataNl`, \'%Y%m\') AS `Ym`, COUNT(*) AS `totale`
FROM `noleggio`
GROUP BY MONTH(`dataNl`)
```

Comment: i only get second-last element in the database

Comment: @L.Antonelli I have updated the answer. Please try the updated code.

Comment: Now i'm getting the same result as my query does, only the existing months. i think grouping is not helping me, because i need to create not existing month "from scratch". my db have date like "12-01-2018, 15-01-2018, 22-03-2018", the 02 month doesn't exist, so how can i get this?